# Renaming Document type once app is in the wild

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I have an document based application with a custom document type.

Any idea how to rename that type once the application has been release, so that the old files are treated the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you flag to re-open when you've edited this question into better shape. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to support both document types, saving only as the newer one. Sooner or later, the older document type will be (mostly) replaced with the newer one.

You can also automatically re-save the older type of document whenever users open it.

Note that resaving documents may have side effects if the file name extension has also changed, because users may have symbolic links to existing documents. The same side effects apply if you brutally search the user home folder to rename all existing documents of the older type. I wouldn't recommend it.

The first approach is just fine, I think, because even if users notice the change, they will attribute it to a file format change or something like that. The biggest downside is that you have to support both document types literally forever.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Fortunately, the document types are identical.  I simply put the name as com.myCompnay.MyDocument instead of "My Document", so now it shows up in the finder as "com.myCompnay.MyDocument".  I want it to be more readable than that...

Comment: Furthermore, I don't want the old name to show up in the save as... list of file formats.